# Using group_by() and prod() for not all rows in each group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to transform this df such that the total is ***only the product of A and B, not including C***

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), type = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'total', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'total'), value = c('1', NA, '4', NA, '5', '4', '8', NA))

 id  type value
  1     A     1
  1     B  <NA>
  1     C     4
  1 total  <NA>
  2     A     5
  2     B     4
  2     C     8
  2 total  <NA>
```

The result should look something like:

```
df_result <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), type = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'total', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'total'), value = c('1', NA, '4', '1', '5', '4', '8', '20'))

 id  type value
  1     A     1
  1     B  <NA>
  1     C     4
  1 total     1
  2     A     5
  2     B     4
  2     C     8
  2 total    20
```

My code so far does the product of all of the types, not just A and B:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    value = as.numeric(value),
    value = if_else(type == 'total', prod(value, na.rm = T), value)
  )
```

***extra:*** what if the id does not uniquely identify one 'set' of types? e.g.

```
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), type = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'total', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'total', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'total'), value = c('1', NA, '4', NA, '2', NA, '4', NA, '5', '4', '8', NA))

 id  type value
  1     A     1
  1     B  <NA>
  1     C     4
  1 total  <NA>
  1     A     2
  1     B  <NA>
  1     C     4
  1 total  <NA>
  2     A     5
  2     B     4
  2     C     8
  2 total  <NA>
```

The totals above would be 1, 2 and 20 respectively.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column which uniquely identifies every set. We can achieve that with the help of `cumsum` and subset the `value` only corresponding to `'A'` and `'B'`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(type == 'total', default = TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(type == 'total', prod(value[type %in% c('A', 'B')], na.rm = TRUE), value)) %>%
  ungroup
  

#      id type  value   grp
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1 A         1     1
# 2     1 B        NA     1
# 3     1 C         4     1
# 4     1 total     1     1
# 5     1 A         2     2
# 6     1 B        NA     2
# 7     1 C         4     2
# 8     1 total     2     2
# 9     2 A         5     3
#10     2 B         4     3
#11     2 C         8     3
#12     2 total    20     3
```

You may drop the `grp` column if it is not needed.

---

For the first case you can do -

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    value = as.numeric(value),
    value = if_else(type == 'total', prod(value[type %in% c('A', 'B')], na.rm = T), value)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` together:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = type, values_from = value
  ) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(total = prod(c(A,B), na.rm =TRUE)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -id,
    names_to = "type",
    values_to = "value"
  )
```

```
  id  type value
1  1     A     1
2  1     B  <NA>
3  1     C     4
4  1 total  <NA>
5  2     A     5
6  2     B     4
7  2     C     8
8  2 total  <NA>
```